Dip in floor when installing new hardwood
I'm installing new hardwood in my kitchen (see image). On the right side of the image, the subfloor has a dip of about 1/8th to 1/4 inch, causing a place where there is a cavity under the floor boards. Is there a way to fill this dip, fix the dip, put shims under the wood, or some function that would resolve this dip? Or will the boards once nailed down "bend" and not be seriously affected by this dip? I have a mixture of board lengths, from 1 foot to 8 foot in length. Should I install mainly short boards on the side where the dip is to allow the joints to flex, or install the long boards on that side to bridge the gap?


You'll probably want to put leveling compound on the floor to make it all flat.  If you don't, those locations where you tried to nail it to the floor where the gap is will cause endless squeaking of the nails holding the floor in place as it flexes through time and foot traffic.  You'll want the whole of the floor supported so there's no chance of flex of the new floorboards.
Also I hope that flooring is just temporarily set in place and not yet attached to each other or the floor.  Otherwise you're going to have a ton of trouble getting the edge pieces to fit in.  Normally a floor is laid from one end to the other, filling a whole row from one side to the other before starting the next row.  You'll also want to stagger the joints from one row to another a lot more than what you have there now, especially on the right side about halfway back.

Yes, they're just set there so I could see what it would look like.
